# Log-Neutralization Example - Help me understand!

Tags: attacks, java

So, I am trying to understand log neutralization and it seems there isn't much documentation or any live/video examples out there to help me understand this. I found a great [GitHub repo](https://github.com/votd/vulnerability-of-the-day) that has many examples of possible vulnerabilities/exploits. So, I spooled up my Kali VM, cloned the repo and compiled the java class and ran it with the make file that accompanied the repo.
I'm not very familiar with Java, I am currently taking a java course though. Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?

Here is the java code:

```
 import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * This class will log anything that comes in through the command line
*    - including CRLF characters
* 
* Use the --safe flag to have it be safe (see the Makefile)
* 
* @author Andy Meneely
* 
*/
public class ArgumentLogger {
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ArgumentLogger.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Logging commandline arguments:");
    if (args.length > 0) {

        // Log safely
        if (args[0].equals("--safe") && args.length > 1) {

            System.out.println("Safe mode enabled.");
            // Encode carrage returns to avoid log forgery
            String clean = args[1].replace('\n', '_').replace('\r', '_');
            log.info(clean);

        // Log unsafely 
        } else {
            log.info(args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the ouput from my console after running ./make:

```
===Exploit===
Logging commandline arguments:
Jan 17, 2017 2:01:46 PM ArgumentLogger main
INFO: a normal event
Apr 25, 2012 1:26:19 PM ArgumentLogger main
WARN: Attack suspected at 129.21.208.62

===Done Safely===
Logging commandline arguments:
Safe mode enabled.
Jan 17, 2017 2:01:47 PM ArgumentLogger main
INFO: a normal event_Apr 25, 2012 1:26:19 PM ArgumentLogger main_WARN:
Attack suspected at 129.21.208.62
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Makefile and compare the parameters in the run.

A CRLF Log Neutralization attack is a way to add arbitrary lines to a log file, if the log file includes information that comes from the user.

That is, the log was trying to put a warning at 2:01, but because of the CRLFs in the string created, it instead put an INFO at 2:01 and the WARN at 1:26 (an arbitrary time chosen by the attacker)

It is a way to add confusion and make tracking the attacker harder.  Fixing it, as shown in the code, is trivial - block non-printable characters and replace them with _

I'll demonstrate what's real and what's fake here :

```
Logging commandline arguments:
Jan 17, 2017 2:01:46 PM ArgumentLogger main <= real date, real location
INFO: a normal event                        <= fake INFO, fake message
Apr 25, 2012 1:26:19 PM ArgumentLogger main <= fake date, fake location
WARN: Attack suspected at 129.21.208.62     <= real message
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This may be a dumb question but, I need to understand this fully so here it goes. When you say the log was trying to put in a WARN, you're saying it was trying to log an instance where the system saw a probable threat/code exception and therefore notify anyone monitoring the log, correct? And instead of the WARN, the neutralization code added a random piece of swapped the WARN to an INFO with a random time to add confusion.
Also, I am [referencing this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels) to define WARN, INFO, etc.

Comment: Well, it didn't swap. It put the fake INFO in, with the real time, then put a fake time for the WARN.

Comment: Logging commandline arguments:
Jan 17, 2017 2:01:46 PM ArgumentLogger main <= real date, real location
INFO: a normal event <= Fake INFO, fake log message
Apr 25, 2012 1:26:19 PM ArgumentLogger main <= Fake date, fake location
WARN: Attack suspected at 129.21.208.62 <= real message

Comment: Thanks again! I appreciate the time you took to explain it!